# Evaluation of q-Pochhammer series

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $f_q(x)$ be the generating function of the sequence $(q;q)_n$:
$$f_q(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (q;q)_n x^n,$$
where $(q;q)_n: = (1-q)(1-q^2) \cdots (1-q^n)$ with convention $(q;q)_0$:=1.

Let $g_q(x):=1/f_q(x)$.

Question: Are there closed form expressions for
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} g'_q(x) \quad \mbox{and} \quad \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} g''_q(x) \quad ?$$
By a rather tricky argument, I get $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} g'_q(x) = -(q;q)_{\infty}$. But I don't get anything simple for $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} g''_q(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$f_q(x)=(q;q)_{\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{1}{(q^{n+1};q)_{\infty}}-1\right)x^n+(q;q)_{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x}.$$
Note that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(q^{n+1};q)_{\infty}}-1=\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1}\frac{q^{(n+1)\ell}}{\ell(1-q^{\ell})}\right)-1\ll \frac{|q|^n}{(|q|;|q|)_{\infty}}
\end{equation}
for sufficiently large $n$. Thus
$$h_q(x):=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{1}{(q^{n+1};q)_{\infty}}-1\right)x^n$$
is analytic for $|x|<|q|^{-1}$.
Hence for $|q|<1$,
$$(q;q)_{\infty}g_q(1-x)=\frac{x}{xh_q(1-x)+1}$$
is analytic for $|1-x|<1/|q|$. Further for $|1-x|<1/|q|$,
\begin{align}
h_q(1-x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{1}{(q^{n+1};q)_{\infty}}-1\right)\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}x^r\\
&=\sum_{r\ge 0}(-x)^r\sum_{n\ge r}(-1)^n\binom{n}{r}\left(\frac{1}{(q^{n+1};q)_{\infty}}-1\right):=\sum_{r\ge 0}\alpha_r(q)x^r.
\end{align}

In particular, we have
\begin{align}
(q;q)_{\infty}g_q(1-x)&=\frac{x}{1+\sum_{r\ge 1}\alpha_{r-1}x^r}\\
&=x-\alpha_1(q)x^2+(\alpha_1(q)^2-\alpha_2(q))x^3+\dots
\end{align}
The following is easy!

Comment: Amazing! Is this an instance of some general method, or did you invent all of it for this particular question??

Answer (score 2):

From $q$-binomial theorem we have
\begin{align}
f_q(x)&=(q;q)_{\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{(q^{n+1};q)_{\infty}}\\
&=(q;q)_{\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{q^{(n+1)k}}{(q;q)_{k}}=(q;q)_{\infty}\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{q^{k}}{(q;q)_{k}}\frac{1}{1-xq^k}
\end{align}
for all $|q|<1$ and $|x|<1$. Therefore for $|1+x|<1$ and $|x|<|q^{-k}-1|, k\ge 1$, 
\begin{align}
\frac{f_q(1+x)}{(q;q)_{\infty}}&=-\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{q^{k}}{(q;q)_{k}}\frac{1}{1-q^k-xq^k}\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{q^{k}}{(q;q)_{k}}\frac{1}{1-q^k}\sum_{r\ge 0}\left(\frac{q^k}{1-q^k}\right)^rx^r\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{r\ge 0}x^r\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{(q;q)_{k}} \left(\frac{q^k}{1-q^k}\right)^{r+1}.
\end{align}
Now, we see that
$$\frac{f_q(1+x)}{(q;q)_{\infty}}+\frac{1}{x}$$
is an analytic function for 
$$x\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<|q^{-k}-1|, k=1,2,\dots\}:=\Omega_q.$$
It is clear that $\Omega_q\neq\emptyset$ is an open set for $|q|<1$. We further have
\begin{align}
\frac{xf_q(1+x)}{(q;q)_{\infty}}&=-1+\sum_{r\ge 1}x^{r}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{(q;q)_{k}} \left(\frac{q^k}{1-q^k}\right)^{r}:=-1+\sum_{r\ge 1}A_r(q)x^r.
\end{align}
Hence
$$(q;q)_{\infty}g_q(1+x)=\frac{-x}{1-\sum_{r\ge 1}A_r(q)x^r}=-x-A_1(q)x^2-(A_2(q)+A_1(q)^2)x^3-\dots$$
is an analytic function at $x=0$. Thus,
$$g_q'(1)=-\frac{1}{(q;q)_{\infty}}\quad\mbox{and}\quad g_q''(1)=-\frac{2}{(q;q)_{\infty}}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{(q;q)_{k}}\frac{q^k}{1-q^k}.$$

Comment: Care to elaborate how you're applying the $q$-binomial theorem? I don't see any $q$-binomial coefficients around...

Comment: Ah, I see. Your second equality sign follows from the identity $\dfrac{1}{\left(x;q\right)_\infty} = \sum\limits_{k\geq 0} \dfrac{x^k}{\left(q;q\right)_k}$, which appears on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#Identities . I still don't see what this identity has to do with the $q$-binomial identity, but at least I see how to prove it: For any $m \geq 0$ and $n \geq 0$, the coefficient of $x^m q^n$ on the left hand side counts the partitions of $n$ into at most $m$ parts, while the coefficient of $x^m q^n$ on the right ...

Comment: ... side counts the partitions of $n$ such that each parts is $\leq m$. But there is a bijection between the former and the latter partitions, given by conjugation (= transposition).

Comment: From what I understand, $f_q\left(1-x\right)$ is not well-defined. But $\dfrac{f_q\left(1-x\right)}{\left(q;q\right)_\infty}$ is well-defined (as a formal power series in $q$ and $x$), because your equality $\dfrac{f_q\left(x\right)}{\left(q;q\right)_\infty} = \sum\limits_{k\geq 0} \dfrac{q^k}{\left(q;q\right)_k} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-xq^k}$ shows that $\dfrac{f_q\left(x\right)}{\left(q;q\right)_\infty} \in \mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]\left[\left[q\right]\right]$ and we can substitute $1-x$ for the *polynomial* indeterminate $x$. But how do you get a $\dfrac{1}{x}$ in the result?

Comment: @ darij grinberg $1/x$ is from $\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{q^k}{(q;q)_k}\frac{1}{1-xq^k}$ with $k=0$ and  substitute $1−x$ to $x$.

Comment: What ring are we working in? Formal power series in $q$ over the rational functions in $x$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see. The canonical injection $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right) \to \mathbb{Q}\left(\left(x\right)\right)$ (sending $x$ to $x$) of the ring of rational functions in $x$ into the ring of Laurent series in $x$ gives rise to a canonical injection $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)\left[\left[q\right]\right] \to \mathbb{Q}\left(\left(x\right)\right)\left[\left[q\right]\right]$ (sending $q$ to $q$). Consider these two injections as inclusions. Then, your first displayed equation shows that $f_q \left(x\right)$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)\left[\left[q\right]\right]$ (or, ...

Comment: ... more formally, to the image of the latter injection). Thus, its inverse $g_q\left(x\right)$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)\left[\left[q\right]\right]$ as well. This allows us to do things like substituting $1+x$ or $1-x$ for $x$ or take derivatives at $x = 1$. In your second-to-last displayed equation, you observe that $\dfrac{xf_q\left(1+x\right)}{\left(q;q\right)_\infty}$ actually lies in $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]\left[\left[q\right]\right]$ (that is, it uses only polynomials, not rational functions in $x$), whence it embeds into $\mathbb{Q}\left[\left[q,x\right]\right]$, and ...

Comment: ... you can compute its $x$-derivative in the latter ring (since the $x$-derivative operators on $\mathbb{Q}\left[\left[q,x\right]\right]$ and on $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)\left[\left[q\right]\right]$ agree on $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]\left[\left[q\right]\right]$). I'm fascinated by how much goes on behind the scenes in seemingly simple Laurent-series arguments.

Comment: @ darij grinberg, Thank you very much!